# RUBY: How to count database column entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new on Ruby, and I have tried to follow some online tutorial, but there something I want to check because I cannot seem to make it work and I am lost right now.

I have set up a database with Ruby to serve as a signup website. This is a simple one liner database and I am using only the default application controller created by ruby. Now for my question.

I want to count all entries from one of my database column which only will have two static entries, (Yes / No), with this I want to count YES as 2 entries and NO as 1 entry and display the total count on index.html.erb, Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

EDIT...

Table = mydb
Column = answer

I have used the following lines to my controller, but when I run the app, I am getting dynamic constant assignment.

```
NO_WEIGHT = 1
YES_WEIGHT = 2
yes_count = ModelName.where(:column_name => "YES").count * YES_WEIGHT
no_count = ModelName.where(:column_name => "NO").count * NO_WEIGHT
```

With that error I replaced the lines with

```
@NO_WEIGHT = 1
@YES_WEIGHT = 2
@yes_count = mydb.where(:answer => "YES").count * @YES_WEIGHT
@no_count = mydb.where(:answer => "NO").count * @NO_WEIGHT
```

with this, I check the logs and I see this

```
Select Count(*) from mydb where mydb.answer = 'YES'
Select Count(*) from mydb where mydb.answer = 'NO'
```

without the expected "* @YES_WEIGHT" as multiplier.

Also I want to try if it display the result on my index.html using the following lines:

```
<p> YES count is <% @yes_count %> </p>
```

but sadly there is no output.

I just want to check how can I fix the dynamic constant to be a static variable for my query to work and display as expected.

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

If you use ActiveRecord you need something like that (the table is users and yes/no is in status column):

```
Users.find(:all,
 :select => "count(*) as status_count",
 :group => "status"
)
```

Comment: The `find` syntax used in your answer is depricated. You should use `where` instead.

Comment: Sorry but is this syntax I need to put in my controller.rb? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, something like this:

```
NO_WEIGHT = 1
YES_WEIGHT = 2
yes_count = ModelName.where(:column_name => "YES").count * YES_WEIGHT
no_count = ModelName.where(:column_name => "NO").count * NO_WEIGHT
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however, is the ModelName is my database table name? and this lines will be under my controller correct?

Comment: I am having problem on the NO_WEIGHT = 1 and YES_WEIGHT = 2 I am having dynamic constant assignment on this. Thanks

Comment: Yes, these should be in your controller. Even if the assignment was dynamic, you could still do pretty much the same thing.

Comment: thanks again for the fast reply, but I cannot run the application without putting an @ in the WEIGHT criteria. Thou I managed to make it run, still I cannot display the counts thou I am calling it out from my index.html

Comment: Could you add your view code, and how you are getting the weights to the question?

Comment: i have used the same thing syntax you have provided me but added a "@" in NO_WEIGHT and YES_COUNT respectively, more over on my index.html I just used <p> No count is <% "@"no_count %> </p> same as the others just to show if it is reading correctly. I am new here so how can I add my view code. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for staying with me.

Comment: Hit edit under your question, and you can edit it, and add the view code.

Comment: I have edited my question. THanks for the help. Am I doing it correctly?